# Angular theme Installation admin-lte-angular

Tags: angularjs, yeoman-generator-angular

I am making use of yeoman angular fullstack generator

i want to install admin-lte-angular theme in my app

i have installed it using bower

but i don't know how install it in angular app

please help to install it

Answer (score 0):

Add the css and the javascript libs to the index.html:

```
<link href="bower_components/admin-lte-angular/admin-lte-angular.css">
// angular.js must be loaded first!
<script src="bower_components/admin-lte-angular/admin-lte-angular.js"></script>
```

Add 'admin-lte-angular' to the module dependencies:

```
angular.module('dashboardApp', [ 'admin-lte-angular' ])
```

Comment: angular.module('dashboardAppApp', [
                            'ngCookies',
                            'ngResource',
                            'ngSanitize',
                            'ngRoute',
                            'btford.socket-io',
                             'ui.bootstrap',
                            'admin-lte-angular', 
                                                    ])    like this way i have added to my app but it seem that app doesn't find admin-lte-angular

Comment: you should remove the comma at the end of your module list `'admin-lte-angular' ])`

Comment: i didn't find this js file and css file in directory that i have installed using bower

Comment: hmm no idea what is the state of your project. can you post a list of your directory structure and the files? specially the bower_components and also post your main/index.html. And what error do you get by the way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this https://github.com/sarahhenderson/admin-lte-angular
Note that the author stated it is a working in progress. So I don't think it is a stable code to use.